# When do i really need redux in react native?

Tags: react-native, redux, state-management

I am started to learn react-native and redux. In some area, can i use redux in some component due to complexity and some component just use a local state in react-native by setState and this.state in the component.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class Blink extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isShowingText: true};

    // Toggle the state every second
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return { isShowingText: !previousState.isShowingText };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    let display = this.state.isShowingText ? this.props.text : ' ';
    return (
      <Text>{display}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The moment you have at least one component that manages its own state instead of emitting actions through the dispatcher, Redux no longer works as intended

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an oversimplified rule of thumb I would say use the Redux store for data which is relevant to different unrelated components and component state for data which has no meaning outside the component and its parent or children.

Redux is basically an in-memory datastore, and adds a lot of boilerplate code to your application if you don't really need it.

Comment: Is your answer still relevant in 2023? Are there any improvements by React Native which removes necessity to use Redux?

Comment: Good question! I typically don't use redux anymore for newer projects. I will now rather use SWR for larger projects, or a simple Provider with Context per domain for smaller projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I have read about Context API. Seems like indeed it removed the need of Redux in simple cases. However, I got a bit confused about you using SWR instead of Redux. To my understanding, these are 2 different concepts. Redux is used for global state management, SWR is library of React Hooks for Data Fetching. What does SWR have to do with global state management?

Comment: If your global state depends on your API, it's possible to leverage the SWR's built-in caching. The entire cache is available from a hook, so could can tap directly into that without hitting an endpoint (assuming the data you need has already been loaded). If you also need to persist it, MMKV + SWR is an excellent combination.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks for the explanation! Also nice hint about MMKV, seems like it's way more powerful than AsyncStorage.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [You Might Not Need Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367) for understanding why should we use Redux. This article is written by author of Redux.

Then, you are able to use both local state and redux store in the your component.

In my opinion, you should use local state for simple app. And Redux for business app, scale feature by the time.

BTW, if the component is too complexity, you should break it into some small component for reuse and control how the state work.